# Exporting interfaces in React Native with Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

I'm working on a login and register screen for my app with the fields username, email, password and token. Instead of creating a [user, setUser] state in each file, I want to create a global interface to use these props globally. Is that possible?

Comment: Maybe you should be using React context?

Comment: I thought it would only work with classes?

Comment: No, there are hooks for creating and consuming context.